# A function f_k(x) -> bool, such that P(f_k(x)) = 1/k, and P(f_k(x) ∧ f_j(x) | j != k) = 1/(jk)

Tags: function

I'd like to have a function

```
bool fun(uint key, uint N);
```

which returns `true` for 1 in `N` values of `key`, assuming `N` is at least 1.  A trivial example satisfying this constraint would be

```
return (key % N) == 0;
```

However, I have an additional constraint: `fun(key, N) && fun(key, M)`, where M != N, must only be `true` for 1 in M×N values of `key`.  The expression above fails that criteria, because `((key % 2) == 0) && ((key % 4) == 0)` is true for 1/4, rather than 1/8, of all values of `key`.

A function that (approximately) satisfies both these properties is

```
return (hash(key ^ hash(N)) % N) == 0;
```

where `hash` is some hash function, like SHA-256.  Is there a way to satisfy these constraints without resorting to a hash function?

**Edited to add:**

An example of an exact solution would be

```
return (key % factorial(N)) < factorial(N - 1);
```

The problem with this function is that factorial(N) quickly gets unreasonably large; the factorial of 58 is larger than 2**256.

My use of this function would be to answer this question: "Does the key `key` belong to shard `N` in my consistent hash of `N+1` shards?"

After seeing the comments, I agree this isn't practical without using a hash-style function, and I've found that three passes of an lcrng, as suggested by Chris Dodd, works well enough.  The specific algorithm I ended up using is the rand_r() code from GNU libc.

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: @Barmar: Any language, although I prefer C.

Comment: This sounds like more of a theoretical question than a practical programming question. Perhaps cs.stackexchange.com would be a better place.

Comment: Your question basically boils down to "Is it possible to define a hash-like function without using a hash function", in which case the answer depends on exactly which functions you think are or are not hash functions.  If you just want a fast hash function, something like one step of a lcrng might be good enough, depending on exactly why you want it....

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I guess what I mean when I'm saying "not a hash function" is something that achieves the result mechanically rather than statistically.  As an analogy, `(key & 1) == 0` for half of all values of key "mechanically", while `(SHA-256(key) & 1) == 0` for half of all values of key "statistically".

Comment: Your 'constraints' are statisical constraints (they're impossible to meet otherwise), so any result is statistical.  In general, to get the form you want, you're going to have fun(k,N) = permute<sub>N</sub>(key) % N == 0, for some (set of) permutations over the possible key values.  So it comes down to choosing permutations that are good/fast enough for whatever you are trying to do.  Fast hash functions are a good choice, and a web search for 'fast hash function' will give you lots of answers.

Comment: Could you show a "truth table", as an example, for `N=4` and `M=5`? (Maybe I should not tackle questions like this at 3:00am, but I think the first condition says that each ROW and each COLUMN of this table must contain exactly one `true` entry, whereas the second condition says that whole matrix/table should also contain exactly one `true` entry - so I probably misunderstood something here...)